# hi I saw there is a problem in stacked line chart if there are negative an positive numbers they dont stack is there away to stack them together?

Tags: charts

in chartjs is there a way to stack positive and negative numbers in line chart? the problem is that the nagtive number dosnt stack with the positive number iam adding acode that works for stacked of positive numbers but if you change one of the values to  a nagitive number you will see it wont work  also adding alink to codepen https://codepen.io/natenorberg/pen/WwqRar

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const colors = {
  green: {
    fill: '#e0eadf',
    stroke: '#5eb84d',
  },
  lightBlue: {
    stroke: '#6fccdd',
  },
  darkBlue: {
    fill: '#92bed2',
    stroke: '#3282bf',
  },
  purple: {
    fill: '#8fa8c8',
    stroke: '#75539e',
  },
};

const loggedIn = [26, 36, 42, 38, 40, 30, 12];
const available = [34, 44, 33, 24, 25, 28, 25];
const availableForExisting = [16, 13, 25, 33, 40, 33, 45];
const unavailable = [5, 9, 10, 9, 18, 19, 20];
const xData = [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: xData,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Unavailable",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.purple.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.purple.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.purple.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.purple.stroke,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      data: unavailable,

    }, {
      label: "Available for Existing",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.darkBlue.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      data: availableForExisting,
    }, {
      label: "Available",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.green.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.lightBlue.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.lightBlue.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.lightBlue.stroke,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      data: available,
    }, {
      label: "Logged In",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.green.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.green.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.green.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.green.stroke,
      data: loggedIn,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    // Can't just just `stacked: true` like the docs say
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }]
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 750,
    },
  }
});
```